# rust nom separated list whitespace sometimes optional

Tags: rust, nom

I'm trying to write a parser using rust and nom which can parse separated lists of tokens with the separator usually surrounded by spaces, but not if the thing between the tokens is in parenthesis.

For example, this is a valid expression: `a and b` as would be `(a)and(b)` or `(a) and b`, however `aandb` is not valid.

For cases other than `(a)and(b)`, the following code works fine. But removing the spaces from `tag(" and ")` makes `(a)andb` valid. How can I support both cases?

```rust
use nom::branch::alt;
use nom::bytes::complete::tag;
use nom::character::complete::{alpha1, char};
use nom::combinator::{all_consuming, complete, verify};
use nom::error::Error;
use nom::multi::separated_list1;
use nom::sequence::delimited;
use nom::{Finish, IResult};

fn parse_token(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    alpha1(i)
}

fn parse_parens(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    delimited(char('('), parse_token, char(')'))(i)
}

fn parse_and(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, Vec<&str>> {
    separated_list1(tag(" and "), alt((parse_parens, parse_token)))(i)
}

fn parse(i: &str) -> Result<Vec<&str>, Error<&str>> {
    let result = all_consuming(complete(parse_and))(i);
    result.finish().map(|(_, o)| o)
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn no_parens() {
        assert!(parse("a and b").is_ok())
    }

    #[test]
    fn parens() {
        assert!(parse("(a) and (b)").is_ok())
    }

    #[test]
    fn mixed() {
        assert!(parse("(a) and b").is_ok())
    }

    #[test]
    fn parens_no_space() {
        assert!(parse("(a)and b").is_ok())
    }

    #[test]
    fn no_parens_no_space() {
        assert!(parse("(a)andb").is_err())
    }
}
```

Comment: Tokenizing and parsing often get's messy and thus often is split into 2 parts you probably should consider that here.

Comment: With your revised `parse_token` `"aandb"` is a valid token, thus it's also a valid list of 1 expression separated by 0 `"and"`.

Comment: you're right, `aandb` should be valid, but `(a)andb` should not. updated again

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to check for a space, closing paren or eof after `parse_token`, this solved the problem for me:

```rust
use nom::branch::alt;
use nom::bytes::complete::tag;
use nom::character::complete::{alpha1, char, multispace0, multispace1};
use nom::combinator::{all_consuming, complete, eof, peek, value};
use nom::error::Error;
use nom::multi::separated_list1;
use nom::sequence::{delimited, terminated};
use nom::{Finish, IResult};

fn parse_token(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    alpha1(i)
}

fn parse_parens(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    delimited(char('('), parse_token, char(')'))(i)
}

fn parse_expr(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    terminated(
        alt((parse_parens, terminated(parse_token, end_of_expression))),
        multispace0,
    )(i)
}

fn end_of_expression(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, ()> {
    alt((
        value((), eof),
        value((), peek(char(')'))),
        value((), char(' ')),
    ))(i)
}

fn parse_and(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, Vec<&str>> {
    separated_list1(tag("and "), parse_expr)(i)
}

fn parse(i: &str) -> Result<Vec<&str>, Error<&str>> {
    let result = all_consuming(complete(parse_and))(i);
    result.finish().map(|(_, o)| o)
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn no_parens() {
        assert!(parse("a and b").is_ok())
    }

    #[test]
    fn parens() {
        assert!(parse("(a) and (b)").is_ok())
    }

    #[test]
    fn mixed() {
        assert!(parse("(a) and b").is_ok())
    }

    #[test]
    fn parens_no_space() {
        println!("{:?}", parse("(a)and b"));
        assert!(parse("(a)and b").is_ok())
    }

    #[test]
    fn no_parens_no_space() {
        assert!(parse("(a)andb").is_err())
    }
}
```